# I'm gettng a error while sending a JSON string using ansible

Tags: json, ansible

Here i want to send a json string to a url . please check my syntax and let me know whats the problem in my code.

ansiblejson.yml

```
hosts:localhost
       sudo:yes
       tasks
       - name:send jenkins-jobs 
         uri
           url:"i gave URL here"
           method:PUT
           return_content:yes
           body:-"{{'Name:sai','Node:node number','EventId:123'}}"
           status_code:204
           body_format:json
```

Here is the error iam getting

```
The error appears to be have in "c:/ansiblejson.yml" line 4, column 8, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be :
sudo:yes
tasks:
     ^ here
```

Comment: Cleaning up unrelated tags, don't do that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please fix the code formatting.
Don't use backspace only whitespace, because of YAML.

Ansible is telling you everything that you need to know, you forgot an semicolon after the tasks section:

```
hosts: localhost
sudo: yes

tasks:
       - name:send jenkins-jobs
```

Also, from Ansible 2.2, you should use not **sudo: yes**, but **become: yes**, and then what user that you want to become; root, sudo etc...